# Mysqldump force BEGIN and END to triggers

Tags: mysql, triggers

Is there a way to force Mysqldump to put the `BEGIN` and `END` instructions around each trigger ?
Because currently, when I do a mysqldump, some triggers does have it, some other triggers does not. And those who don't have it make the import crash afterwards. So I want to set these instructions around each triggers.

I have been searching since some days on the web for something like this, but I did not found.

Thanks by advance for the help ! :)

> MySQL version : 5.7.27
> Mysqldump version : ver 10.13 distrib 5.7.27

Comment: 'Mysqldump to put the BEGIN and END instructions around each trigger ' - I can't imagine so - dump is pretty simple  , and triggers with only 1 statement doen't need them. Nothing to stop you writing code to do so but your best bet is to 'fix' your triggers to a standard.

Comment: @P.Salmon The trigger is standard, it has been generated by mysql itself. And when I dump using other things that mysqldump, it is working well. The problem is only with mysqldump...